# Java Tic Tac Toe check winner methods not working together

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Hello I have a problem with a tic tac toe game I wanted to try and make. I am still a beginner so please feel free to give tips about organization and stuff like that but my problem is that my methods, checkRowWin, checkColoumnWin, and E.T.C do not seem to be working when added together. They all seem to work individually and when added together the one that is called last is the only one that works. I can't seem figure it out on my own.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToeATREU {
   public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 3;
   public static final String PLAYER_ONE = "x"; //Sets piece to corresponding player
   public static final String PLAYER_TWO = "o";
   public static void main (String []args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[][] gameBoard = new String[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
      String playerTurn = PLAYER_ONE;
      boolean gameWon = false;
      intro();
      playGame(gameBoard,console,playerTurn,gameWon);
   }
   public static void fillBoard(String[][] gameBoard) { //Fills board with all underscores
      for(int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < gameBoard[i].length; j++) {
            gameBoard[i][j] = "_";
         }
      }   
   }
   public static void printBoard(String[][] gameBoard) { //Prints gameBoard array so that it looks like a tic tac toe board 
      for(int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
         String[] tempArray = gameBoard[i];
         for(int j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(tempArray[j] + " ");
         }
      }
   }
   public static void intro(){ //Intro Message to let brief players on rules
      System.out.println("This program allows you to play a game of Tic-Tac-Toe.");
      System.out.println("Each player will be prompted for the location");
      System.out.println("to place their piece. When one player has filled");
      System.out.println("an entire row, column, or diagonal the game is won.");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Player 1, you will be x");
      System.out.println("Player 2, you will be o");
      System.out.println();
   }
   public static void takeTurn(String[][] gameBoard,Scanner console, String playerTurn) { //Method for placing piece each turn into board and then reprinting board
      if(playerTurn == PLAYER_ONE) { // Tests to see which player is making move
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Make your move player 1:");
      }
      else { 
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Make your move player 2:");
      }   
      System.out.print("What row? ");
      int rowMove = console.nextInt();
      System.out.print("What column? ");
      int columnMove = console.nextInt();
      if(playerTurn == PLAYER_ONE) { //test to see which player is making move and places corresponding piece
         gameBoard[rowMove-1][columnMove-1] = PLAYER_ONE;
      }
      else { 
         gameBoard[rowMove-1][columnMove-1] = PLAYER_TWO;
      }
      System.out.println();
      printBoard(gameBoard);
   }
   public static String playGame(String[][] gameBoard, Scanner console, String playerTurn, boolean gameWon) { //Method for playing one game of tic tac toe
      //boolean gameWon = false;
      int currentPlayer = 1; //this currentPlayer variable is just to offset the game reporting the congratulations method for the losing player
      fillBoard(gameBoard);
      printBoard(gameBoard);
      while(gameWon == false) { //while this loop is false, the game will play
         takeTurn(gameBoard,console,playerTurn);
         if(checkRowWin(gameBoard,playerTurn) = true) {
            gameWon = true;
         }
         gameWon = checkRowWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
         gameWon = checkColoumnWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
         gameWon = checkDiagonalWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
         gameWon = checkTie(gameBoard,playerTurn);
         if(playerTurn == PLAYER_ONE) { //for switching players after every call of take turn method
            playerTurn = PLAYER_TWO;
            currentPlayer = 1;
         }
         else {
            playerTurn = PLAYER_ONE;
            currentPlayer = 2;
         }   
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Congratulations Player " + currentPlayer + "! You win!");
      return playerTurn;
   }
   public static boolean checkRowWin(String[][] gameBoard, String playerTurn) { //checks for three pieces in a row to decide if the game has been won
      boolean rowWin = true;
      for(int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
         String[] tempArray = gameBoard[i];
         for(int j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++) {
            if(!tempArray[j].equals(playerTurn)) {
               rowWin = false;               
            }
         }
         if(rowWin == true) {
            return true;
         }
         else { 
            rowWin = true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
   public static boolean checkColoumnWin(String[][] gameBoard, String playerTurn) { //checks for three pieces in a coloumn to decide if the game has been won
      boolean coloumnWin = true;
      for(int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < gameBoard.length; j++) {
            if(!gameBoard[j][i].equals(playerTurn)) {
               coloumnWin = false;
            }
         }
         if(coloumnWin == true) {
            return true;
         }
         else {
            coloumnWin = true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
   public static boolean checkDiagonalWin(String[][] gameBoard, String playerTurn) { //checks for three pieces in a diagonal of the board to decide if the game has been won
      boolean diagonalWin = true;
      for(int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
         if(!gameBoard[i][i].equals(playerTurn)) {
            diagonalWin = false;
         }

      }
      if(diagonalWin == true) {
         return true;
      }
      else { 
         diagonalWin = true;
      }      
      for(int j = 0; j < gameBoard.length; j++) {
         int row = j;
         int coloumn = BOARD_SIZE-1-j;
         if(!gameBoard[row][coloumn].equals(playerTurn)) {
           diagonalWin = false;
         }
      }

      if(diagonalWin == true) {
         return true;
      }
      else { 
         diagonalWin = true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   public static boolean checkTie(String[][] gameBoard,String playerTurn) {
      boolean test = true;
      for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            if(gameBoard[i][j].equals("_")) {
               test = false;
            }

         }
      }   
      return test;
   }
}
```

Comment: *"please feel free to give tips"* - Learn to live without `static`

Comment: And learn not to use == to compare String values.  It probably works OK in this particular program, but usually, it won't.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Might be suitable for a question on it's own, but why live without static?

Comment: use .equals in string to string comparison instead of ==, <somestring>.equals(<somestring>)

Comment: @QueenSvetlana Java is OO language, might as well take advantage of it. `static` also creates more problems than it solves. In most cases it abused in such away as to circumvents the concept of encapsulation of property management, which leaves the values in unknown states (from one moment to another) - `static` has a place, but not in like this

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
gameWon = checkRowWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
gameWon = checkColoumnWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
gameWon = checkDiagonalWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
gameWon = checkTie(gameBoard,playerTurn);
```

means that the results of the first three lines are discarded, and overwritten by whatever checkTie() returns - i.e., if checkRowWin() returns True, then nothing is done about it.

The code has other issues that may be best suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

This line should use comparison instead of assignment (or just remove the comparison entirely, since it evaluated to a boolean regardless):

```
if(checkRowWin(gameBoard,playerTurn) = true) {
```

Here you need to make sure not to overwrite `gameWon`:

```
     gameWon = checkRowWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
     gameWon = checkColoumnWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
     gameWon = checkDiagonalWin(gameBoard,playerTurn);
     gameWon = checkTie(gameBoard,playerTurn);
```

The quickest solution would be:

```
 gameWon = checkRowWin(gameBoard,playerTurn)      || 
           checkColoumnWin(gameBoard,playerTurn)  ||
           checkDiagonalWin(gameBoard,playerTurn) || 
           checkTie(gameBoard,playerTurn);
```